# S_realloc: How to increase the length of a *numeric* vector? (first argument not char*)

Tags: c, r, memory-management

In C code called from R via .Call, I pass a `double *vector` to a function for
filling `vector` with numbers. I don't know how large `vector` will be in the
end, so I keep track of its number of elements `vector_size` and use
`S_realloc(vector, vector_size+64, vector_size, vector_size * sizeof(double))`
to increase the size by 64 doubles in case necessary. `R CMD check` complains
about the first element of `S_realloc` being `double *` instead of `char *`. Can
I use `S_realloc` in this case at all? How would one increase the length of a
*numeric vector*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be as easy as adding a cast

```
  foo = S_realloc((char*) p, n1, n2, n3);
```

where `p` is your `double *p`.

There is also an alternate form

```
 TYPE* Calloc(size_t N, TYPE)
 TYPE* Realloc(ANY *P, size_t N, TYPE)
 void Free(ANY *P)
```

per [Section 6.1.2 User-controlled Memory](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#User_002dcontrolled-memory) of *Writing R Extensions*.

*Edit:* Corrected initial comment re Section 6.1.2.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for helping. Originally, there were two warnings, now there is one left: `warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'double *' from 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] vector = S_realloc((char *) vector, ...`. I'll look into `Realloc` next then.

Comment: You may need the cast on the assignment too. This  is standard C stuff, and as you prefer this API ...

Comment: Hi, worked, also with `vector = (double *) Realloc(vector, vector_newsize, double)`. Thanks, Dirk!